# How can i remove an table's tr with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

first of all, super beginner here. I'm trying to do a to do list. The add part works fine, it looks like this:

```js
let salvar = document.getElementById("salvar")
let remove = document.getElementById("remover")


salvar.onclick = saveitem

function saveitem() {
  let item = document.getElementById("input").value
  let novoitem = document.createElement("tr")
  let lista = document.getElementById("todoitems")
  novoitem.innerText = item
  lista.appendChild(novoitem)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<div class="container">
  <button id="salvar">Save</button>
  <button id="remover">Remove</button>
</div>

<table id="todoitems">
  <tr>
    <th>Tarefa</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can i create a function that removes the last added item?

Comment: You cannot put text directly in a `tr`, you need to have `td` or `th` children. There you can put text inside.

Comment: I've corrected markup errors as well as answered your question, along with an explanation of how the `removeLastItem()` function works. Please check it out.

Comment: While I understand that you like the solution which you picked as an answer, that is also an unfortunate pick as it does not do what your question asks for: *How can i create a function that removes the last added item?* The second reasons the answer you picked is not a good choice is that it does not address the invalid HTML problem I explained and fixed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we need to use correct markup for your table. `tr` must be a child of either `thead` or `tbody`. Secondly, you cannot have text nodes as children of `tr`; these must be placed in `td` or `th` elements. Also it's bad practice to use non-English variable names, I've changed that to English.

That being said, here's your solution:

```js
let add = document.getElementById("add")
let remove = document.getElementById("remove")

remove.onclick = removeLastItem;
add.onclick = saveitem;

function saveitem() {
  let item = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let list = document.getElementById("todoitems");
  newRow.innerHTML = `<td>${item}</d>`;
  list.appendChild(newRow);
}

function removeLastItem() {
  document.querySelector('#todoitems tr:last-child')?.remove();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<div class="container">
  <button id="add">Save</button>
  <button id="remove">Remove</button>
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tarefa</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="todoitems"></tbody>
</table>
```

Explanation of the `removeLastItem()` function:

```
document.querySelector('#todoitems tr:last-child')?.remove()
```

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) allows you to pass in a CSS selector that works just like it does in CSS. To select the last `tr` in the  `tbody#todoitems` you use `#todoitems tr:last-child` as your CSS selector. The `?` is the [safe navigator/optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) that makes sure your code doesn't throw an error if someone clicks the remove button when there are no items in your table.

Comment: When i use query selector i select things just like i do in CSS?

Comment: Yes, I've also linked the documentation in my explanation.

Comment: newRow.innerHTML = `<td>${item}</d>`;. What about this, you created the HTML of a table's td? Why the ${item}?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('todoitems').lastChild.remove()
```

use last child property

Answer (score 2):

instead of using remove button you can add button inside tr and when pressed it can delete the that tr for you

```
function saveitem(){
let item = document.getElementById("input").value
let novoitem = document.createElement("tr")
let delBtn = document.createElement("button")
delBtn.innerText = "del"
delBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    novoitem.remove();
})
let lista = document.getElementById("todoitems")
novoitem.innerText = item
lista.appendChild(novoitem)
novoitem.append(delBtn);
}
```

Comment: How can i make the button be added at the right side of the new added tr? Like as a new table column

Comment: This does not fix the invalid HTML problem. You must not add textnodes to a `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allElm = document.getElementById("todoitems").getElementsByTagName("tr");
allElm[allElm.length-1].remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let salvar = document.getElementById("salvar");
let remove = document.getElementById("remover");


salvar.onclick = saveitem;
remove.onclick = removeitem;
function saveitem(){
let item = document.getElementById("input").value;
let novoitem = document.createElement("tr");
let lista = document.getElementById("todoitems");
novoitem.innerText = item;
novoitem.onclick = function() {this.remove();};
lista.appendChild(novoitem);
}
function removeitem() {
  document.getElementById("todoitems").lastChild.remove();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
    <div class="container">
        <button id="salvar">Save</button>
        <button id="remover">Remove last</button>
    </div>

    <table id="todoitems">
        <tr onclick="this.remove();">
            <th>Tarefa</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Are you want this
kui klõpsate tr-ile, siis see kustub!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to pass id using `this` in the js code and then call function on click. This way you can delete any item from the list and not the last item added. Here's the sample code i wrote for you with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfhassaan/3wzfkh26/):

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<div class="container">
  <button id="salvar">Save</button>
  <button id="remover">Remove</button>
</div>

<table id="todoitems">
  <tr>
    <th>Tarefa</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```
let salvar = document.getElementById("salvar")
let remove = document.getElementById("remover")


salvar.onclick = saveitem

function removeItem(item){
    item.remove();
}

function saveitem() {
  let item = document.getElementById("input").value
  let novoitem = document.createElement("tr")
  let lista = document.getElementById("todoitems")
  novoitem.setAttribute('id',item);
  novoitem.setAttribute('onClick','removeItem(this)');
  novoitem.innerText = item
  lista.appendChild(novoitem)
}
```

This will remove the item you click on the list.